# Absolute div scroll in scrollable div

Tags: html, css

Our problem: I make one div and make one other div for hover this div and I use absolute  position, but parent div make scrollable div then this absolute  position div is not scroll .
so ***how to scroll this div in scrollable div?***

I make hover div like this :

```
#hover {
height: 56px;
    left: 158px;
    top: 156px;
    width: 56px;
    border: 2px dashed red;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

check this link :http://jsfiddle.net/kamlesh0606/yrjPA/

see hover div( red border) in jsfiddle link .

I make one hover div on other div in scrollable main div. So I make hover div using absolute position. but I got one problem: when main div scroll then this hover div is not scroll like relative div. So how to scroll hover div in scrollable div?

Comment: i make one hover div on other div in scrollable main div. see in link. so i make hover div using absolute position . but i got one problem : when main div scroll then this hover div is not scroll like relative div. so how to scroll hover div in scrollable div?

Comment: what actually is the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div id="hover">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

you must put your absolute div in relative div